# ASP.NET MVC - Session Expired presented with Login View as a Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I've noticed that If I use an Ajax.ActionLink on my View and my Session has expired (For Example.. I've been inactive for a while). Instead of being re-directed to the Login View, it loads within the `UpdateTargetId` set in my Ajax.ActionLink. How would I resolve this?

Comment: Can't you ask in the controller if session is null and redirect to another action? I use $.ajax with the same problem so I check which data return and redirect if session is null.

Comment: No because its an AJAX request, if it fails, it fails before reaching the Action I want it to reach. I've tried handling it in the OnBegin, OnFailure and OnComplete callbacks of an Ajax.ActionLink but to no avail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
  if(Request.IsAuthenticated == false)
  {
    throw new HttpException(500, "message here");
  }
  else
  {
    // logic here
  }
}
```

And then implement a function for the `OnFailure` property of the `AjaxOptions` of your ActionLink that redirects to the login page. Do not throw a 404 because it will cause the login view to load in the `UpdateTargetId` again.

Comment: This doesn't work as it doesn't get to the server due to it not running "MyAction" as it's already failed before reaching "MyAction"

Comment: Did you remove the authorize attribute from the function?

Comment: Ahh ofcourse, I had the [Authorize] attribute on my controller.